# jQuery load function can't won't load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on this [website](http://orchidaberdeen.com/) for quite some time now and i've encountered a bug that is trumping me at every point.

The problem is in the gallery section of the site. When a user clicks on the circle the website splits open to reveal more thumbnails. When the user clicks on the smaller thumbnails a lightbox is supposed to appear.

Sadly this is not the case, i think it's due to the fact that there is to much jQuery being loaded at once. As the thumbnail pages are external html files being loaded by jQuery so when i try to load the lightbox plugin the browser doesn't seem to want to load it.

The lightbox effect works when the page is viewed on it's own individual pages for example here, http://orchidaberdeen.com/6_toggle/1.html

These are the things i've tried,

```
(function loading() {
  $.get('js/view.min.js?auto', function() {
    $('body').load('6_toggle/1.html#externalContent');
  });
})();
```

I've also tried this,

```
$(".plus_1").click(function() {
  $.getScript("js/view.min.js?auto", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
     console.log(data); //data returned
     console.log(textStatus); //success
     console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
     console.log('Load was performed.');
  });
});
```

This line of code is loading the external html files,

```
t_slide.load("6_toggle/"+page+".html", function() {
```

If anyone has any suggestions or knows of a fix that can re-trigger jquery after a page load or knows if this isn't even possible then it would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Cameron

Comment: am seeing multiple loading of the same scripts as well as jQuery itself being loaded every click. Spend some time in `Network` tab of console. Over-writing scripts, especially jQuery can cause all sorts of problems... including wiping out plugins attached to jQuery. If it was me I would create a standalone module and make it work before full integration into master page

Comment: Hi there, the reason your seeing multiple loadings of the same scripts is because i wanted to get the individual pages working first before i posted for help. So in order to do so i needed to place some js scripts into the individual index files, i would remove these once a solution has presented itself. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: make sure `t_slide` is defined. I see it defined as a `var` inside a function in one place. If that is only place, then you have a scope problem. Test for `t_slide.length`